# filtering one list based on another list c#

Tags: c#

I have two lists.

The **first** list is a list of members with a MemberKey that identifies the member.

The **second** list is a list `memberKeys`;

I want to filter the member list by the memberKeys in the list of memberKeys.

```
List<Member> membersList = GetMembers();
List<int> memberKeys = // list of member keys to find
List<Member> members = memberList.Where(x => x.MemberKey ????? // in the memberkeys list
```

Answer (score 4):

Quite simple this way:

```
List<Member> members = memberList.Where(x => memberKeys.Contains(x.MemberKey)).ToList();
```